# Parallel nested operations return weird results

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

I'm trying to use the Parallel library for my code and I'm facing a strange issue.
I made a short program to demonstrate the behavior. In short, I make 2 loops (one inside another). The first loop generates a random array of 200 integers and the second loop adds all the arrays in a big list.
The issue is, in the end, I don't get a multiple of 200 integers, instead I see some runs doesn't wait for the random array to fully be loaded.
It's difficult to explain so here the sample code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestParallel
{
    class Program
    {
        static int RecommendedDegreesOfParallelism = 8;
        static int DefaultMaxPageSize = 200;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int maxPage = 50;
            List<int> lstData = new List<int>();
            Parallel.For(0, RecommendedDegreesOfParallelism, new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = RecommendedDegreesOfParallelism },
                (index) =>
                {
                    int cptItems = 0;
                    int cptPage = 1 - RecommendedDegreesOfParallelism + index;
                    int idx = index;
                    do
                    {
                        cptPage += RecommendedDegreesOfParallelism;
                        if (cptPage > maxPage) break;

                        int Min = 0;
                        int Max = 20;
                        Random randNum = new Random();
                        int[] test2 = Enumerable
                            .Repeat(0, DefaultMaxPageSize)
                            .Select(i => randNum.Next(Min, Max))
                            .ToArray();
                        var lstItems = new List<int>();
                        lstItems.AddRange(test2);
                        var lstRes = new List<int>();
                        lstItems.AsParallel().WithDegreeOfParallelism(8).ForAll((item) =>
                        {
                            lstRes.Add(item);
                        });

                        Console.WriteLine($"{Task.CurrentId} = {lstRes.Count}");
                        lstData.AddRange(lstRes);
                        cptItems = lstRes.Count;
                    } while (cptItems == DefaultMaxPageSize);
                }
            );
            Console.WriteLine($"END: {lstData.Count}");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is an execution log :

> ```
> 4 = 200
> 1 = 200
> 2 = 200
> 3 = 200
> 6 = 200
> 5 = 200
> 7 = 200
> 8 = 200
> 1 = 200
> 6 = 194
> 2 = 191
> 5 = 200
> 7 = 200
> 8 = 200
> 4 = 200
> 5 = 200
> 3 = 182
> 4 = 176
> 8 = 150
> 7 = 200
> 5 = 147
> 1 = 200
> 7 = 189
> 1 = 200
> 1 = 198
> END: 4827
> ```

We can see some loops return less than 200 items.
How is it possible?

Comment: [Threading in C# - Part 2: Basic synchronization](https://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx) by Joseph Albahari.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This here is not threadsafe:

```
lstItems.AsParallel().WithDegreeOfParallelism(8).ForAll((item) =>
{
    lstRes.Add(item);
});
```

From the documentation for `List<T>`:

> It is safe to perform multiple read operations on a List, but
> issues can occur if the collection is modified while it's being read.
> To ensure thread safety, lock the collection during a read or write
> operation. To enable a collection to be accessed by multiple threads
> for reading and writing, you must implement your own synchronization.

It doesn't explicitly mention it, but `.Add()` can also fail when called simultaneously by multiple threads.

The solution would be to lock the calls to `List<T>.Add()` in the loop above, but if you do that it will likely make it slower than just adding the items in a loop in a single thread.

```
var locker = new object();

lstItems.AsParallel().WithDegreeOfParallelism(8).ForAll((item) =>
{
    lock (locker)
    {
         lstRes.Add(item);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation :) I'm gonna learn a bit more seriously about threadsafing